# What is the best way to parse my file into my sql tables

Tags: c#, linq, stream

I have a data file that is not a straight forward flat file, I need to put into a SQL tables using C#. I am  new to C# and not really sure how to go about doing this and what features of c# should i use, e.g. streamreader , LINQ or anything else or combination.

I have tried basic streamreader and linq.

I have tried below but unsure how to get cut the data to get what i need.

```
IEnumerable<string> strCSV =
                 File.ReadLines(FilePath);
            var results = from str in strCSV
                          let n = str.Split(',')
                          where !n[0].EndsWith("SYSWARN")

                          select str;


            List<string> lst = new List<string>();
            lst = results.ToList();
```

Data file string below(below is a two rows of data)

```
*2019:01:09:00:00:35:GMT: subject=BMRA.SYSTEM.FUELINST, message={TP=2019:01:09:00:00:00:GMT,SD=2019:01:08:00:00:00:GMT,SP=48,TS=2019:01:08:23:55:00:GMT,FT=INTIRL,FG=-441}
2019:01:09:00:00:35:GMT: subject=BMRA.SYSTEM.FUELINST, message={TP=2019:01:09:00:00:00:GMT,SD=2019:01:08:00:00:00:GMT,SP=48,TS=2019:01:08:23:55:00:GMT,FT=INTNED,FG=949}*
```

It need to it look like the data below so it becomes comma delimited and the i would like to cut the data even further to get the specific records that i need.

```
*2019:01:09:00:00:35:GMT: subject=BMRA.SYSTEM.FUELINST,TP=2019:01:09:00:00:00:GMT,SD=2019:01:08:00:00:00:GMT,SP=48,TS=2019:01:08:23:55:00:GMT,FT=INTIRL,FG=-441
2019:01:09:00:00:35:GMT: subject=BMRA.SYSTEM.FUELINST,TP=2019:01:09:00:00:00:GMT,SD=2019:01:08:00:00:00:GMT,SP=48,TS=2019:01:08:23:55:00:GMT,FT=INTNED,FG=949*
```

Answer (score 0):

Try regex :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Globalization;


namespace ConsoleApplication125
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string pattern1 = @"(?'time'.*):GMT: subject=(?'subject'[^,]+), message=\{(?'message'[^}]+)";

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string line = "";
            while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Match match = Regex.Match(line, pattern1);

                DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(match.Groups["time"].Value, "yyyy:MM:dd:HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                string subject = match.Groups["subject"].Value;
                string message = match.Groups["message"].Value;

                string pattern2 = @"(?'key'[^=]+)=(?'value'[^,]+),?";
                MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(message,pattern2);
                Dictionary<string, string> dict = matches.Cast<Match>()
                    .GroupBy(x => x.Groups["key"].Value, y => y.Groups["value"].Value)
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
            }
        }

    }

}
```